# Excel VBA Find Method for specific column

Tags: vba, excel

VBA find method seems to fail when I am trying to search for the value in specific column. 
This code

```
Sub TargetR()
Dim CLL As Range
Dim TargetRange As Worksheet
Dim R As Range

Set CLL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("J29")
Set TargetRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set R = TargetRange.Cells.Find(CLL.Value)

If Not (R Is Nothing) Then
    Debug.Print R.Address
Else: Debug.Print "Empty"
End If

End Sub
```

works perfectly. 
While the search limited by the column with keyword header fails:

```
Sub Target()
Dim CLL As Range
Dim TargetRange As Worksheet
Dim targetColumn As Range
Dim sColumn As Range


Dim R As Range

Set CLL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("J29")
Set TargetRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set sColumn = TargetRange.Cells.Find("This Column")
Set targetColumn = sColumn.EntireColumn
Set R = targetColumn.Cells.Find(CLL.Value)

If Not (R Is Nothing) Then
    Debug.Print R.Address
Else: Debug.Print "Empty"
End If

End Sub
```

Specifying search direction through xlByColunm does not help

Comment: What does `Set sColumn = TargetRange.Cells.Find("This Column")` give you? you also need to check if `sColumn` is nothing before assigning it to `targetColumn`

Comment: I just tested the code. it works for me. BTW `.Find` retains the last setting. Ensure you set all parameters. For example`LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False`

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below (explanation inside the code as comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Target()

Dim CLL As Range
Dim TargetRange As Worksheet
Dim sColumn As Range
Dim R As Range

Set CLL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("J29")
Set TargetRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Set sColumn = TargetRange.Cells.Find("This Column")
If Not sColumn Is Nothing Then ' <-- make sure Find was successful
    Set R = sColumn.EntireColumn.Find(what:=CLL.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)        
    If Not R Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print R.Address
    Else: Debug.Print "Empty"
    End If
Else ' Find failed to find "This Column"
    MsgBox "Unable to find 'This Column'"
End If 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As I figured out, Find method do not work correctly if value that needs to be found contained in merged cell, and Find methoud applied only for the leftmost  column, that contain part of that merged cell. For my VBA code to work properly, some additional merge check , and subsequent extension of search area was the answer

```
If sColumn.MergeCells Then
                Set sColumn = Column.Resize(,Column.MergeArea.Columns.Count)
```